# Created Uri Scheme not launching an app Windows Phone

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, uri-scheme

I am creating a Uri Scheme for my app by following the steps [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/jj206987%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)

To test this I created another simple app to launch the original app with a click event

```
    private async void Button_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        await Windows.System.Launcher.LaunchUriAsync(new System.Uri("startbackgroundwallpaper:"));
    }
```

In the original app I have the `UriSchemeMapper` class

```
namespace StartBackgroundWallpaper
{
    class UriSchemeMapper : UriMapperBase
    {
        private string tempUri;

        public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
        {
            tempUri = System.Net.HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString());

            // no parameters, desired launch to MainPage. no further code here.

            return uri;
        }
    }
}
```

In the `InitializePhoneApplication()` method in `App.xaml.cs` of the original app I have

```
      RootFrame.Navigated += CompleteInitializePhoneApplication;

        //Handle custom uri scheme
        RootFrame.UriMapper = new UriSchemeMapper();
```

Now if the original app is not installed, it is correctly listed in the search result when the `Button_Click` is raised in the simple app. But when it's installed, the `loading...` screen is showing but the app never loaded.

In the app `WMAppManifest.xml` I have also added

```
<Extensions>
  <Protocol Name="startbackgroundwallpaper" NavUriFragment="encodedLaunchUri=%s" TaskID="_default" />
</Extensions>
```

What am I missing?

Answer (score 1):

I think it might be because your URI doesn't return anything.
I don't know if you solved your problem yet but if not, in your UriSchemeMapper class, try replacing your line "return uri;" by this

```
return new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
```

Not sure this is your problem though, hope it helps

Answer (score 0):

Currently, your mapper isn't doing any actual mapping so you never return a XAML page to land the user on. Without a successful initial navigation, the shell will display the loading screen until the watchdog timer kicks in and kills your app.

Florian.C's answer is close - you do indeed need to return a reference to MainPage.xaml for cases where you are launched via your URI scheme. However, once you attach a UriMapper to your RootFrame, it will be called for every navigation. Consequently, you need to check whether this is an initial navigation based on your scheme or just another navigation within your app.

```
public override Uri MapUri(Uri uri)
{
     var tempUri = HttpUtility.UrlDecode(uri.ToString());

     if (tempUri.Contains("encodedLaunchUri=startbackgroundwallpaper"))
          return new Uri("/MainPage.xaml", UriKind.Relative);
     else
          return uri;            
}
```